# Using OnGuard to add licensing to application

Tags: delphi, delphi-11-alexandria, onguard

I want to use OnGuard to lock my program after 1 day unless you enter an activation key specific to your computer.  I would like to change the start date and end date of ogdatecode. For StartDate I need the first time the app has run on this computer ever, and the end date would after one day. After expiration, I need a form to open where you have to enter an activation code specific to your computer.

```
procedure TMainMenuForm.OgDateCode1GetKey(Sender: TObject; var Key: TKey);
begin
  Key := CKey;
end;

procedure TMainMenuForm.OgDateCode1Checked(Sender: TObject;
  Status: TCodeStatus);
begin

 case Status of
  ogValidCode: Showmessage ('------ Valid Code ------' +#13+#13+'      Until : 19/08/2021 ' +#13+#13+'               Reste' +#13+#13+'                  '+ #13+#13+ '                days'+#13+#13+ '------------------------');
  ogInvalidCode: Showmessage ('áÇ íãßä ááÈÑäÇãÌ Ãä íÚãá Ýí åÐÇ ÇáÊÇÑíÎ');
  ogPastEndDate: Showmessage ('ÊÇÑíÎ ÕáÇÍíÉ ÇáÈÑäÇãÌ ÇäÊåÊ .. ÅÊÕá ÈÇáãÈÑãÌ');
  end;

 if Status <> ogValidCode then
 begin
  Showmessage ('äÃÓÝ .. ÓíÊã ÛáÞ ÇáÈÑäÇãÌ');
  Application.Terminate;
 end;
end;
```

Comment: This is all covered in the documentation for OnGuard, which is still available in PDF format from the same place you got OnGuard.